# create multiple imageviews programmatically alongside each

Tags: android, download, android-imageview

I want to display multiple image views from URL place alongside each

My xml is :

```
  <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </LinearLayout>

   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

My java code :

```
 Drawable imgg;
 ImageView image;
 LinearLayout layout;
 layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imgLayout);
 private void grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception 
 {
    imgg = Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(), "src");
 }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class DownloadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String _ads;
    public DownloadImageFromURL(String ads)
    {
        _ads = ads;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

         image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
         image.setId(imgId++);
            try
            {
                grabImageFromUrl("http://dariran.com/Ads/Mobile/Small/" + _ads);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

   }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        try
        {
            image.setImageDrawable(imgg);
            layout.addView(image);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

`DownloadImageFromURL Class` built on a loop syntax(images count)

I loaded images but they placed on each other
I don't know why can't display true.

Comment: use universal image loader library to load images from internet.It's very easy and it saves images in cache.

Comment: my image loader works fine. but it's displaying are great problem

Comment: hey you need to specify positon

Comment: what is  specify position?  android:orientation="horizontal" says to put images alongside each

Comment: when you add views to your horizantal layout you need to specify position .. Someone deleted the answer.. It was correct layout.addView(view,index)

Comment: thanks, i tested : with imgCount = 0; layout.addView(image,imgCount++);   but not working

Comment: what is happening now ?

Comment: images stored on alongside of each

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73825/discussion-between-preethi-rao-and-user3404171).

Comment: sorry do you have gmail for chat? i don't know how can chat with this website

Comment: Just click on the link..( continue this discussion in chat.)

Comment: Who is returning imgg ? is it a drawable ? when you download image you get it in bitmap form right ?

Comment: imgg is a drawable obj. you can use : "http://dariran.com/Ads/Mobile/Small/e.jpg"   manualy. i found an exception : it returned : the specified channel could not be found. you must call removeview()

Comment: It means it is not able to download image ..

Comment: @PreethiRao Hello...
Am struggling with similar issue..Through json am getting multiple url's.I can decode them and get a image..But the issue is in created image views dynamically in Async class and assigning the decoded image to that image view..Could you please help me in solving this if possible..